# Is there a way to specify that QSizeGrip work on which parent widget?

Tags: qt

I have a `QSizeGrip` that has a `QWidget` parent and this parent also has another `QWidget` parent, But I want to use this sizeGrip only for it's parent, not parent of it's parent. I don't want this sizeGrip work on top-level window.

Is there any way to do this? How can do this?

Comment: [QSizeGrip](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qsizegrip.html#details) docs say: `The QSizeGrip class provides a resize handle for resizing top-level windows.`

Comment: Thank you. I solved this problem using `eventFilter` protected function and `case QEvent::MouseButtonPress`, `case QEvent::MouseMove`, `case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease`

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer and accept it when you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install event filter for the `QSizeGrip`:

```
p->size_grip = new QSizeGrip(0);
p->size_grip->installEventFilter(this);
```

And then in `eventFilter`:

```
bool MyClass::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e)
{
    if(o == p->size_grip)
    {
        switch(static_cast<int>(e->type()))
        {
        case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
            if(static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(e)->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
            {
            }
            break;
        case QEvent::MouseMove:
            //resizing...
            return true;
            break;
        case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
            if(static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(e)->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
            {
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return QWidget::eventFilter(o,e);
}
```