# Resizing QLabel using QSizeGrip

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

Actually I want to create a `QLabel` which can be resized by the user, So I found the QSizeGrip class which is used to resized parents window, but actually I want to use this QSizeGrip on my label so that using that grip user can resize my label but the problem I am facing is that this grip when i use with my label resizing my widget window not the label so please provide me code how to make this grip works on `QLabel` instead of my widget window. My class till now which inheriting the `QLabel`.

```
 class resizeLabel: public QLabel
    {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    resizeLabel(QWidget *parent=nullptr): QLabel(parent){
        setFrameShape(QFrame::Box);
        QSizeGrip *resizing= new QSizeGrip(this);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to specify that QSizeGrip work on which parent widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538444/is-there-a-way-to-specify-that-qsizegrip-work-on-which-parent-widget)

Comment: No, This didn't answer my question but I have solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 
`setWindowFlags(Qt::SubWindow);`
That statement after creating `QSizeGrip` object, This flag will sit this grip to resize the `QLabel` insted of the widget window.